# How can I make a DIV enclose two inside sections?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code:

```
    <section id="content" class="grid_9">
      <div class="block-content grey-bg">
        <div class="container_12">
            <section class="grid_6 aa">
                ... lots of content ...
            </section>
            <section class="grid_6 aa">
                ... some content ...
            </section>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

When I look in the browser there is a grey background because of my grey-bg class but it doesn't enclose the two grid_6 sections. Actually it acts like there's nothing inside it at all. The area of the teo grid_6 sections overflows out below the grey background. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong. Sorry I forget to mention I am using the 960 grid system. Thank you.

Comment: We might need to see some CSS to go with that code. No, we will need to. Definitely.

Comment: We need an example (pictures or live). Showing us some random HTML with some class names is pretty meaningless here.

Comment: @rlemon - sorry. Actually I have no CSS defined for anything other than the grey-bg and the css for that is just making it grey. The rest is just the 960 grid CSS that describes only width.

Comment: @Melina http://jsfiddle.net/ providing a live example will help.. and the 960 grid system is defined CSS... showing us the applicable code form this will help. We are not here to do the research for you :P com'on now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that your `<div class="block-content grey-bg">` contains all of its floats. 960.gs does this by applying a "clearfix" on its `container_#` classes. If you need other elements to have this same behavior, you can manually apply 960.gs's `clearfix` class to that element:

```
<div class="block-content grey-bg clearfix">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `clear: both` to the css for the block-content or grey-bg class.

For example:

```
div.block-content {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: In the 960 grid you already have the **special classes** `.clear` and `.clearfix` so take a closer look, no need to create extra classes in this case. (I know the OP mentioned it a bit after) +1 anyway

Answer (score 0):

Which Browser are you viewing it on. Since you are using HTML5 tags, it wont render correctly on IE unless you declare it.

Cheers,